# Below is my code, I have an error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm new to react native, I'm trying to work on the TouchableOpacity onPress to navigate to SignUp screen:
However, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Below is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

function Regform ({navigation}) {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.regform}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}> Welcome! </Text>
                <Text style={styles.header}>Let's begin. Please fill out the information below.</Text>

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Your name"
                    style={styles.textinput}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => React.yourdob.focus()} />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Your date of birth"
                    style={styles.textinput}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                    ref={(input) => React.yourdob = input}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => React.youremail.focus()} />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Your email"
                    style={styles.textinput}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                    ref={(input) => React.youremail = input}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => React.passwordInput.focus()} />

                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Your password"
                    style={styles.textinput}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                    ref={(input) => React.passwordInput = input} />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} 
                **onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')} >**
                    <Text style={styles.btntext}>Sign up </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
export default Regform;
```

Comment: I assume you don't pass navigation to the component

Answer (score 0):

`react-navigation` passes `navigation` object to it's direct child. So I guess Regform is not a direct child of the navigation. You can pass navigation object from ancestors which are child of the navigation or use `useNavigation`.

Comment: How to make Regform a direct child of the navigation?  Can you let me know how to correct the code specifically? I'm so new to this but what you have said make sense in a higher understanding level.

Comment: @nancyruya Sure, which version of `react-navigation` are you using? you can find it's version in `package.json` file.